# Error-Pivot table Pivotfield method failed

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am writing data from datatable to a new created excel sheet-sheet1.Then want to create pivot table on Sheet2.here after writing data to sheet1 m saving sheet1.then creating pivot table object and adding Pivot Field.
here m getting error-

Answer (score 0):

Please explain the structure of your imported table in Sheet1.

Does your table have ONE ROW of UNIQUE HEADINGS?

Is your entire table, header & data, including any data you have added to the table, contiguous?

Comment: My Table is having 38 columns and 218 rows.I have added data to columns using for loop on sheet1.than i saved the sheet1.Now at sheet2 m creating a pivot table.its giving error while m adding any fields to Pivot table.Error-Pivot table Pivotfiled Method failed.